# AngularFire: Extend $firebaseArray with 'order' attribute to retrieve child order in line easily

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

For my Waitlist application, I use `$firebaseArray` to synchronize a queue of guests. The guests array is ordered by wait time (i.e. time since the guest child was added to the `$firebaseArray`).

Each guest should be able to see their own order in line, but not the other waiting guests. Therefore, for each guest in the list, I want to keep their current order in line as an attribute, e.g. `orderInLine`.

For example:

```
guests: {
    guest1: {
        name: "John",
        orderInLine: 1
    },
    guest2 {
        name: "Jane",
        orderInLine: 2
    }
    ...
}
```

My current workaround is to loop over the list until I find a match and use the loop index as the place in line, along:

```
// Find place in line for selected guest
for (var i = 0; i < guests.length; i++) {
    if (guests[i] === selectedGuest) {
        selectedGuest.orderInLine = i + 1;
    }
}
```

One problem is that I need to load all guests for this operation.

I assume/hope the solution is to `$extend` the `$firebaseArray` and for every `$$added`, `$$removed` or `$$moved` keep the `orderInLine` attribute for each child updated, but I haven't been able to figure out a good implementation for this.

Any help to solve this would be greatly appreciated. Here is a [fiddle playground.](https://jsfiddle.net/h3g2mrmd/8/)